# How to get payload description about reported state of a thing in aws iot core?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-nodejs, aws-iot-core

I am building a service where the updated state of a thing is downstreamed to a HTTP endpoint that processes the payload. This endpoint can get data from different aws iot things and hence it needs to know the format of the payload for parsing.

---

For example: a temperature sensor can send:
`{reported: {temperature: 35}}`
,whereas a camera can send `{reported: {event: "person-detected"}}`

> Is there a AWS IoT Thing SDK to retrieve the payload description of a
> thing, so that the downstream endpoint can process the payloads
> automatically based on the thing type or thing group that published
> the messages?